# Url format in android

Tags: android

My application should send a https GET request.

Every time I get an exception from it. If I uncomment     `url = "http://www.example.com"` it works perfect. Otherwise it throws an exception "`Illegal character in scheme at index 3`".

How to fix it?

```
   public class TestHttpManager {

   private final static String mask= "httрs://%s/action/?key=%s&param1=%s&param2=%s&param3=%s";

   public static void Send() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
           if (....)
              url = String.format(UrlMask, "anyHostName.com", "keyTest", "param1", "param2", "param3");

             //url = "http://www.example.com";
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
             request.setURI(new URI(url));
             client.execute(request);
        }

     }
```

**UPDATE**: I have an error `Tagret host must not be null, or set in parameters` too.

Comment: you want to post data to server? using http post? or you want to parse xml which you are getting after hitting that url

Comment: Could you log the result of `url = String.format(UrlMask, "anyHostName.com", "keyTest", "param1", "param2", "param3");` ? That would be a sure-fire way of knowing what the illegal character might be.

Comment: httрs://serverName.com/action/key=myKey&param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=param3

Comment: try using url = "https://www.example.com";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have done `url = "http://www.example.com"+stringOfParameter;`

now use this function to well format the above `url`,

```
url = new String(url.trim().replace(" ", "%20").replace("&", "%26")
.replace(",", "%2c").replace("(", "%28").replace(")", "%29")
.replace("!", "%21").replace("=", "%3D").replace("<", "%3C")
.replace(">", "%3E").replace("#", "%23").replace("$", "%24")
.replace("'", "%27").replace("*", "%2A").replace("-", "%2D")
.replace(".", "%2E").replace("/", "%2F").replace(":", "%3A")
.replace(";", "%3B").replace("?", "%3F").replace("@", "%40")
.replace("[", "%5B").replace("\\", "%5C").replace("]", "%5D")
.replace("_", "%5F").replace("`", "%60").replace("{", "%7B")
.replace("|", "%7C").replace("}", "%7D"));
```

and now use the **formatted url**.

**EDIT :** 
In your case you got `httрs://serverName.com/action/key=myKey&param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=param‌​3`

with mask, I dont know much about that, but you can do

```
String urlLink = "httрs://serverName.com/action/";
String paramLink = "key=myKey&param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=param‌​3";
```

and then use the above answer.

Comment: How to use it? I have the url mask `mask= "httрs://%s/action/?key=%s&param1=%s&param2=%s&param3=%s";`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String host = "https://" + serverAddress + "/";
String encodedUrl = host + URLEncoder.encode(url, "utf-8");
```

It should encode only parameters, but not host.

Answer (score 0):

If you use like  this `url = "http://www.example.com"` it will work fine, but if you want to add sub path then you have to do like this `Uri.encode(edittext.getText())` and add it to your url like this `url = "http://www.example.com" + Uri.encode(edittext.getText())`.  Don't try to do it manually..

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

The URL is not well formed. There is no question mark, nor is there a reference to an actual page. It look be something like:

"httрs://%s/action.php?key=%s&param1=%s&param2=%s&param3=%s"

Comment: a reference to an actual page isn't necessary. I added the question mark, but there's no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you as well:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
request.setURI(new URI(URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - but could you try connecting to your web service as HTTP instead of HTTPS? I'm not sure if `DefaultHttpClient` is capable of doing HTTPS without additional setup.

Comment: Uh oh .. hold on .. at what point is the exception being thrown? Is it at `new URI(url)`? In that case, you could ignore my answer above.